# Cardinality of positive rationals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

The cardinality of $Q ∩ (0,∞) ≤$ the cardinality of $\Bbb R × \Bbb R$.

I know that the cardinality of $\Bbb R × \Bbb R$ is $c$, however I don't know how to simplify $Q ∩ (0,∞)$, it doesn't include the negative irrational numbers?

Comment: The question's title is not very useful. Something like "Cardinality of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,\infty)$" would be better.

Comment: If you are supposed to demonstrate it by producing an injection from $\Bbb Q\cap(0,\to)$ to $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, just use the map $q\mapsto\langle q,0\rangle$; it’s easy to verify that this is an injection.

Answer (score 2):

This is the intersection of $Q$ with $(0,\infty)$, so the positive rationals.  But all you really need for this question is the fact that it is a subset of $R$.